# Android MediaRecorder - Loop Recording

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I want to implement loop video recording (e.g., DVR devices for vehicles/cars work this way).

`MediaRecorder` has `setMaxDuration` method:

> After recording reaches the specified duration, a notification will be
>   sent to the MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener with a "what" code of
>   MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED and recording will be
>   stopped. Stopping happens asynchronously, there is no guarantee that
>   the recorder will have stopped by the time the listener is notified.

So when it reaches that "max duration" it stops recording but asynchronously and how can I start a new recording session if previous one can still be in progress?

Should I create a new instance of `MediaRecorder` for the next recording session? Will it work fine?

```
private val infoListener: MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener =
    MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener { mr, what, extra ->
        when (what) {
            MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED -> {
                // I want to start a new recording session
            }
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a continuous recording application, **setMaxFileSize()** is more useful, because the MediaRecorder will send a **MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_APPROACHING** code to OnInfoListener, at which point your application can call [**setNextOutputFile()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setNextOutputFile(java.io.File)) to set the next filename and allow the MediaRecorder to continue into the new file without stopping and restarting the recording from the application. If you know the video and audio bitrates, you can estimate the file size corresponding to your desired duration. It is will not be the exact duration, but still useful for accomplishing basic chunked recording.

Your application will need to keep track of the files you create and delete the old ones if you want to implement a circular recording scheme with a limited total storage size.

Comment: no, sorry, but using `setMaxFileSize` is ridiculous. DVR loop recording should be based on time and not the size, and the size of video file can be vary based on video recording quality

Comment: I agree and would prefer to use setMaxDuration for this purpose for my own application. However, that functionality does not exist, so I calculate file size based on my known bitrates, and am accurate to within 2%.  Maybe if we both request this feature, they will add it.